# Want to get only one row and other rows blank rows while joining

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have One table called tableA :

```
Col1            Col2           Col3
------------------------------------
A25             45              12
A25             45              12
A25             45              12
B26             10              20
```

another table called  tableB :

```
Col1                     Col2
------------------------------
A25                       D1
A25                       D2
A25                       D3
B26                       D4
```

When I join these two tables in SQL(T-SQL) with tableA.Col1 = tableB.Col1 I **only want to get the first row of the equal left table rows once and the others are blanks**.

My joining query in my own words is :

```
Select
  tableA.*, -- IF THERE ARE NO DUPLICATES,
            -- BUT PUT BLANKS FOR SUCCESSIVE ROWS IF THERE ARE DUPLICATES
  tableB.Col2
from tableA JOIN tableB
where tableA.Col1 = tableB.Col1
```

In other words I want the result like this

```
Colm1       Colm2       Colm3          Colm4
-------------------------------------------- 
A25          45           12             D1   
                                         D2
                                         D3
B26          10          20              D4
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What you are trying to do in SQL should be done at the presentation level, e.g. in a reporting tool. A SQL query is supposed to provide the application with data, then it's up to the application how to actually display them.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are working on a presentation layer. SQL Server does not excel at this, but it can be done. Be sure to use an Order By to ensure you have the correct row order. See this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6603e/13).

```
Select 
 Colm1 = Case When RowId = 1 Then TableA.Col1 Else '' End
  ,Colm2 = Case When RowId = 1 Then Convert(varchar, TableA.Col2) Else '' End
  ,Colm3 = Case When RowId = 1 Then Convert(varchar, TableA.Col3) Else '' End
  ,Colm4 = TableB.Col2
From TableA
  Join
    (
      Select Col1
        ,Col2
        ,RowId = Row_Number() Over (Partition By Col1 Order By Col2)
      From TableB
    ) TableB
    On TableA.Col1 = TableB.Col1
Group By   TableA.Col1
  ,Case When RowId = 1 Then TableA.Col1 Else '' End
  ,Case When RowId = 1 Then Convert(varchar, TableA.Col2) Else '' End
  ,Case When RowId = 1 Then Convert(varchar, TableA.Col3) Else '' End
  ,TableB.Col2
Order By TableA.Col1, TableB.Col2
```

**Update: now shows blanks instead of nulls**

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT  x.*, y.Col2, y.Col3
FROM
(
    SELECT  b.Col1, b.Col2, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY b.Col1 ORDER BY b.Col2) RowNum
    FROM    dbo.TableB b
) x
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT  TOP(1) a.Col2, a.Col3
    FROM    dbo.TableA a
    WHERE   x.RowNum = 1
    AND x.Col1 = a.Col1
) y
```

Comment: This answer gets most of the work done. However, I think you are specifying the wrong alias in your outer apply - you should be using `x` instead of `b`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4cde6/11):

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN B.Row = 1 THEN A.Col1 END A,
CASE WHEN B.Row = 1 THEN A.Col2 END B,
CASE WHEN B.Row = 1 THEN A.Col3 END C,
B.Col2 D

FROM
(SELECT  Col1,Col2,Col3
 FROM Table1
 Group By Col1,Col2,Col3
) AS A
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT Col1, Col2 ,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY Col1) AS ROW FROM Table2
) AS B
ON A.Col1 = B.Col1
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
SELECT 
    case when row_number() over(partition by a.col1 order by a.col1)=1 then a.col1 else ' ' end, 
    case when row_number() over(partition by a.col1 order by a.col1)=1 then convert(varchar,a.col2) else ' ' end, 
    case when row_number() over(partition by a.col1 order by a.col1)=1 then convert(varchar,a.col3) else ' ' end, 
    b.col2
FROM(select distinct col1, col2, col3 from tableA) a
INNER JOIN tableB b 
ON(a.col1=b.col1)
```